# DatatypeConverter.parseDate is outputting wrong date

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, date-conversion

Given this little piece of code:

```
// import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

Date date = DatatypeConverter.parseDate("2012-07-12-04:30").getTime();
System.out.println(date);
Date date2 = DatatypeConverter.parseDate("2012-07-12+00:00").getTime();
System.out.println(date2);
```

Output is:

```
Thu Jul 12 00:00:00 VET 2012
Wed Jul 11 19:30:00 VET 2012
```

Why is converted date 4:30 behind given date? I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

"2012-07-12+00:00" - it's 12 Jul 2012 00:00 in UTC timeZone OR 11 Jul 2012 19:30 in Venezuela TimeZone.

You get string representation of that time in your local timezone, but anyway Date class is timeZone-bound to UTC

Comment: Date has no timezone at all. It's DatatypeConverter choosing to interpret the string as UTC time that's the cause.

Comment: yes, you're right. I probably mentioned time-zone in wrong way. Date contains count of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 00:00 UTC, but really it has no time-zone inside.